# @media not working on phone but does on desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I created my website and want to make it mobile friendly.
So I created a media query and started working with it. Checking while scaling my browser window.

If I check the same page on a phone it doesn't change the layout.

I can't see what I'm missing.
Here is what I have:
HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  h2{
    font-size:2.5vw !important;
  }
}

h2{
    font-size:1.5vw;
}
```

Hope I missed just a small thing :-)

M.

Comment: Well how wide is your phone's screen?

Comment: Smaller then the 768px... It's 320px

Comment: Maybe viewport units `vw` are not supported on your phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to tell the device to use its actual pixel width:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Some devices will render pages assuming they are not optimized for mobile. Put that meta tag in your `<head>` tags and let us know if that fixes it. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: This was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this into your code:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) { ... }
```

OR

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) { ... }
```